# Setting custom route to device in local network

Tags: networking, router, routing, nas

I have a little problem with my local network. When laptop(marked by red arrow) tries to connect to my NAS(Zyxel NSA310) it sends file not by shortest possible route (via switch only), but instead its sending it trough router and 2 powerlines which significantly slows transfers.(I tried to connect NAS to router and acces it from my PC and transfers were significantly better).My question is can i force my laptop or nas to send transfer files via specific route(or shortest one)?

[image: my local network]

Comment: How did you find out that the traffic goes via the Powerline adapters? Which IP addresses do the devices have? What kind of NAS is that, and which operating system is the NAS and the PCs?

Comment: Assuming this is a flat, single subnet LAN, If your assumption that traffic flows back to the router then to the NAS is correct, then your problem is the switch, it should know where the NAS and laptop are automatically and route traffic directly between those 2 nodes without sending it back to the router. If your assumption is just because of transfer speeds, best to look at that separately, bad patch cord(s) or switch, or the switch isn't capable of the speeds you expect.

Comment: @stueja "How did you find out that the traffic goes via the Powerline adapters? " - I created setup like [this](https://imgur.com/tBmvyQz) [and as you see](https://imgur.com/a/nE3XS) (second sreen) transfers are much much better, with setup with switch between speed decreased but ist still pretty high (3 scren and last).

The nas is [NSA310](http://www.zyxel.com/support/SupportLandingSR.shtml?c=gb&l=en&kbid=MD09121&md=NSA310), switch is [Tenda s108](http://www.tendacn.com/in/product/S108.html) and both pc have windows 10.

Comment: I have ip addres(pc) 192.168.0.4, laptop 192.168.0.5, NAS 192.168.0.6
@acejavelin Yes its single subnet lan

Comment: Unplug the cable between switch0 and powerline1, you should still be able to access the NAS, that should confirm whether traffic is flowing back or not

Comment: Could you add a `route print` and `arp -a`to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that all you devices are in the **same subnet**. A basic function of the router is to connect between two or more, different, subnet.

You need to **change the IP range** on at least one side of the router, to make sure they are of different ip subnet ranges.

Heres another way to put it, each subnet can be considered a broadcast domain. the router splits broadcast domains. Each broadcast domain has a unique IP range (as long as they are connected to each other directly, indirectly, or remotely).

Here, maybe the laptop is '*confused* ' about where the destination address network lies.